# For which positive integers k is this series convergent: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)^2}{(kn)!}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

The above series can be simplified as:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(k)^n}$$

Does it mean that there is no such a positive integer k exits so that the series converges? If not, what's wrong with my analysis? And how to fix it?

Comment: Your simplification is incorrect.  Example: $\frac{(4!)^2}{(2\cdot 4)!} = \frac{1}{70}\neq \frac{24}{16}$

Comment: $\dfrac{(n!)^2}{(kn)!} \not = \dfrac{n!}{(k)^n}$

Comment: The case $k=2$ is not settled using the ratio test, so it needs a different approach. Have you at least tried running numerical tests with specific values of $k$ to get a feel for how the terms in the series decay?

Answer (score 1):

First we need $a_n \to 0$. We have $a_n = \dfrac{(n!)^2}{(kn)!} \sim \dfrac{2\pi n \left(\dfrac{n}e\right)^{2n}}{\sqrt{2\pi kn} \left(\dfrac{kn}e \right)^{kn}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{\sqrt{k}} \dfrac1{k^{kn}} \left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{(2-k)n}$.

Hence, $k \geq 2$ the series converges by comparison test.